# Does app engine support memcache for .Net Core?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, memcached

I'm just porting existing .Net based application to .Net Core for hosting it on Google App Engine. Our application uses memcache.
Need to make sure, does app engine support memcache for .net core or are there any plans to implement it in future?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET is only available for App Engine **Flex**, whereas App Engine memcache is only available on **Standard** runtimes.

Instead, you could use Redis Cloud as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/using-redislabs-redis).

Comment: Wish there is any update in supported Languages for Memcahce as Cloud Memorystore (Redis Cloud) is still in beta.